# What are the differences between these polkadot binaries: polkadot, polkadot-parachain, polkadot-prepare-worker, polkadot-execute-worker?

Tags: polkadot, polkadot-sdk

In the old polkadot repo [release page](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases) prior to the polkadot-sdk repository merge, polkadot had only one binary called `polkadot` (there is also `staking-miner` but it has been moved to its own repo: [paritytech/staking-miner-v2](https://github.com/paritytech/staking-miner-v2)).

In recent [releases](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/releases) of paritytech/polkadot-sdk v1.1.0 and v1.2.0, we have four of them:

- `polkadot`
- `polkadot-parachain`
- `polkadot-execute-worker`
- `polkadot-prepare-worker`

What are the respective usages of all these binaries? If I want to launch a polkadot validator, which binary should I use?

Answer (score 1):

All three binaries are needed to properly run a validator node.

The main `polkadot` binary is started by a user to run the node, as it always has been. After this PR ([98.6% OF DEVELOPERS CANNOT REVIEW THIS PR! [read more...]](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/7337)) you need two auxiliary binaries, `polkadot-prepare-worker` and `polkadot-execute-worker` which are not intended for any user interaction and are only run by the node software itself. The auxiliary binaries are actually only required if the node runs as a validator, but in the current design, the node will fail to run without them even if it's not a validator.

See also the wiki on how to [Installing the Polkadot binaries](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-validate-polkadot#installing-the-polkadot-binaries)